# Why do I get <nativehr>0x80131904</nativehr> when connecting to a Site-URL?

Tags: 2010, exception

I have a virtual machine I use for SharePoint 2010 developement. On this machine I have all rights all permissions. The SQL Server runs there and SharePoint is installed. In this VM I created a Winforms application which reads and handles SharePoint data, mainly list manipulation. It works fine.

The first thing the application does is receiving all list names from a user specified Site-URL via this method:

```
public static List<String> GetAllListNames(string _siteURL) 
{
    List<String> listNames = new List<string>();

    try 
    {
        using (SPSite site = new SPSite(_siteURL.Trim()))
        {
            using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
            {
                SPListCollection lists = web.Lists;

                foreach (SPList l in lists)
                {
                    listNames.Add(l.Title);
                }

            }
        }            
    }
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
    }

    return listNames;
}
```

Now I published the applicatio via Click-Once and installed it on another server (Windows Server 2008 R2). This machine also has SharePoint installed on it. I also have full permission for the site I am trying to connect. Still when I try to connect/ get all list names I get the following Error:

> Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException --->
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80131904):
>   0x80131904    bei
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.GetListsWithCallback(String
>   bstrUrl, Guid foreignWebId, String bstrListInternalName, Int32
>   dwBaseType, Int32 dwBaseTypeAlt, Int32 dwServerTemplate, UInt32
>   dwGetListFlags, UInt32 dwListFilterFlags, Boolean bPrefetchMetaData,
>   Boolean bSecurityTrimmed, Boolean bGetSecurityData, Boolean
>   bPrefetchRelatedFields, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter p2DWriter, Int32&
>   plRecycleBinCount)    bei
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetListsWithCallback(String
>   bstrUrl, Guid foreignWebId, String bstrListInternalName, Int32
>   dwBaseType, Int32 dwBaseTypeAlt, Int32 dwServerTemplate, UInt32
>   dwGetListFlags, UInt32 dwListFilterFlags, Boolean bPrefetchMetaData,
>   Boolean bSecurityTrimmed, Boolean bGetSecurityData, Boolean
>   bPrefetchRelatedFields, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter p2DWriter, Int32&
>   plRecycleBinCount)    --- Ende der internen Ausnahmestapelüberwachung
>   ---    bei Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.HandleComException(COMException comEx)
>   bei Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetListsWithCallback(String
>   bstrUrl, Guid foreignWebId, String bstrListInternalName, Int32
>   dwBaseType, Int32 dwBaseTypeAlt, Int32 dwServerTemplate, UInt32
>   dwGetListFlags, UInt32 dwListFilterFlags, Boolean bPrefetchMetaData,
>   Boolean bSecurityTrimmed, Boolean bGetSecurityData, Boolean
>   bPrefetchRelatedFields, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter p2DWriter, Int32&
>   plRecycleBinCount)    bei
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListCollection.EnsureListsData(Guid webId,
>   String strListName)    bei
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListCollection.Undirty()    bei
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPBaseCollection.GetEnumerator()    bei
>   MPToolBoxServerSide.SharePoint.SPAdapter.GetAllListNames(String
>   _siteURL)

I tried to look up (0x80131904) on the web. SQL Content-DB's Log becoming to big seems often to be the reason for this issue. In my case it is not.

Also when I tried to install the application previously I had an issue with Interop not being installed in the GAC on the second server so I removed all (Interop) references from the project as it still compiles and works fine on my developement machine.

So is it possible that the application simply still misses some .dll but the Exception ctached is not detailed enough? Or is there something els.e I missed?

Btw if I try to execute the very same method using CSOM I can access data without any problems even when the application is not installed on the server but on a Client machine.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: this error 0x80131904 is not from sharepoint rather it is from SQL Server. Possible issues are Temp DB drive or Content DB running out of space, No permission on the database. http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/t/73346.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is related to your url, as the client object works I believe that the offending line is:

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(_siteURL.Trim()))
```

use instead:

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(_siteURL))
```

You could test the theory by hard coding the url:

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://teamsite.sitesh.com/checkthisout/"))
```

**EDIT**

for the error your now getting the solution would be found here:

http://blog.sharepointrx.com/2009/08/26/the-web-application-at-url-could-not-be-found-verify-that-you-have-typed-the-url-correctly-if-the-url-should-be-serving-existing-content-the-system-administrator-may-need-to-add-a-new-request-url/

similar error to yours but related:

> The web application at [URL] could not be found. Verify that you have
>   typed the url correctly. If the url should be serving existing
>   content, the system administrator may need to add a new request url
>   mapping to the intended application.

this is due to an account that you were using had access to the DB whilst another did not so sharepoint coundnt find the web application.

adding db_owner would give full access to the content database for anyone who is part of that group (like site collection admins)

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180977(v=sql.90).aspx

Comment: When I try to connect a hardcoded site-url I get System.IO.FileNotFounexception: The Webapplication  could not be found... I do not understand why Trim() does affect the url-string anyway?! It did NOT on my developement machine. Weird!

Comment: check this out for your new error: http://blog.sharepointrx.com/2009/08/26/the-web-application-at-url-could-not-be-found-verify-that-you-have-typed-the-url-correctly-if-the-url-should-be-serving-existing-content-the-system-administrator-may-need-to-add-a-new-request-url/

Comment: what account privlages are used in your test account compared to dev?

Comment: I have 'Full access' to the Site on both the dev and productive machines.

Comment: but the account that your using are they both site collection admins? have you tried with different accounts?

Comment: Omfg I will kill myself someday over this whole Sharepoint-HELL. I followed the instructions described in the link you shared in the comment above and it worked for one account if I try to do the same thing with any other account I still get the <nativehr>-Error.

Comment: Ok latest Update, I had no permissions for one of the Content_databases.

Comment: does it solve the issue, or are you still experiencing issues?

Comment: Following the instructions in your link and getting db_owner permissions for the content databases solved the issue. Thank you!

Comment: no probs happy to help!

Comment: Please add the url to your awnser and also write about the content-db, I will mark it as awnser.

Comment: just ammended my answer!